# JavaScript's Equivalent of %[flag][width] (C & Java Format Specifier)

Tags: javascript, html, css, string-formatting, format-specifiers

I want to preserve white space like this:
**[  1 h   2 m   3 s]**
**[11 h 22 m 33 s]**
I want the 'h', 'm', and 's' stay in the same position every time they update their value (In my code, I put 1s interval).
In this case, I want it to preserve 2 character long for the numeric value.

And here's my problem:
**[1 h 2 m 3 s]**          
(The problem)
Its Width changes as the total character changes.
**[  1 h   2 m   3 s]**    
(The way I wanted it to be)

In C, in this case, I can easily solve the problem by using:

```
printf("%2d h %2d m %2d s", h, m, s);
```

Unlike JavaScript, I found no solution to this on the internet.
Btw, here's my code:

```
var s = 0;
setInterval(() => {
    timer.innerHTML = s < 60 ? (s % 60) + ' s' :
        s < 3600 ? Math.floor(s / 60) % 60 + ' m ' + (s % 60) + ' s' :
        Math.floor(s / 3600) + ' h ' + Math.floor(s / 60) % 60 + ' m ' + (s % 60) + ' s';
    s++;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Are you aware that browsers disregard repeated whitespace in markup values?  This is expected behavior.  The whitespace is there, but ignored.  To change this you can use a `<pre>` tag, or style your elements with `white-space: pre`.

Comment: You can use [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

Comment: As mentioned by @Taplar this is more a browser issue and his advice is pretty spot on.  Additionally you could also use html entities to preserve the space as well with &nbsp;

Comment: @Taplar I knew about the `<pre>` tag, but I just don't see a way to **preserve** the white space directly from JavaScript. Or is it impossible?

Comment: You need to experiment with the `padStart` that CodeManiac suggested.  What you are talking about has two parts; making the html not ignore the white space, and making the strings always be a consistent length, which means conditionally *adding* white space.

Comment: I've seen the `padStart` just now, and I think it might work.
Thanks @Taplar, @Code Maniac, @jgetner

Comment: You can possibly code it with the [template literals](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings) but it isn't builtin as far as I know. You'd better off finding a third-party library.

Comment: as @tamplar said it is a browser thing. It ignores whitespace. What you could do however is instead of using whitespace is to use `&nbsp;` you can add several of those and the browser will render them as whitespace.

Comment: Or another trick I can think of would be to use html for styling. You could output a `<span>` tag around the hour, minute and second and set a width on the span and right align the text in it. This way it will always look the same no matter if you have 1 or 2 numbers in the box since your width would be the width of 2 digits + the letter.

Comment: @DanielDimitrov Thank you for the solution! I'll try that soon.

Answer (score 0):

Final solution I came up with after recieving several tips from the comments is this:

```
var s = 0;
setInterval(() => {
    let sec = (s % 60).toString().padStart(2);
    let min = (Math.floor(s / 60) % 60).toString().padStart(2);
    let hour = Math.floor(s / 3600).toString().padStart(2);
    timer.innerHTML =   s < 60 ? `${sec}s` :
                        s < 3600 ? `${min}m ${sec}s` :
                        `${hour}h ${min}m ${sec}s`;
    s++;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: just so you know. `padStart()` does not work in IE, even more recent versions. See https://caniuse.com/#search=padstart